Using `Scaled` in an `Epilog` to `Plot`
I want to plot a simple function with added text:
Plot[1/5*x^5 + 1/3*x^3 + x, {x, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["text here", {2, 250}]}]


However, I want this text to appear at x = 2 horizontally, but always 2/3 of the way up the PlotRange. (This is to accommodate adding scaling factors to the function.) But this doesn't work:
Plot[1/5*x^5 + 1/3*x^3 + x, {x, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["text here", {2, Scaled[2/3]}]}]


How do I accomplish this - i.e., fixed on one axis, but Scaled on the other?

Perhaps you could use Rescale to also convert the x-coordinate into a relative position?
Plot[1/5*x^5 + 1/3*x^3 + x, {x, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> Text["text here", Scaled[{Rescale[2, {-5, 5}], 2/3}]]]



(+1) it also functions nicely with PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 100}}
